# How can I make mkdocs support Markdown documentations in multiple locations?

Tags: markdown, mkdocs, python-markdown

MkDocs is a great tool for documentation based on Markdown language. However, currently it only supports documentations in one specific location as this document shows (see [mkdocs configuration](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/)):

> docs_dir
> The directory containing the documentation source markdown >files. This can either be a relative directory, in which >case it is resolved relative to the directory containing your configuration file, or it can be an absolute directory path from the root of your local file system.

> default: 'docs'

However, in my case my Markdown files are located in several locations, and they do not share the same parent directory. Any ideas on how I can make mkdocs search for several documentation folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work on linux you can easily make a general `docs` folder and use softlinks `ln -s /real/path/for/part1 docs/part1` to bring them together. Now mkdocs will work like everything is in the same parent directory.

On Windows the same may be possible using `mklink`.